# Fetch Api get params

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a "GET" request using window.fetch, and I need to pass in a param which takes in an entire array as the value. For example, the request url should look like this

```
'https://someapi/production?moves=[]'
```

I have the following segment, which ends up in a 400 request, because the array gets evaluated to empty

```
let url = new URL('https://someapi/production');
let params = {moves: []};
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));
console.log(url);
fetch(url.href)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(val => {
          console.log(val);
     });
```

Upon inspecting the url.href looks like

```
https://someapi/production?moves=
```

where as I want it to be

```
https://someapi/production?moves=[]
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(params[key])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second argument of `url.searchParams.append(key, params[key])` is not a string, [`URLSearchParams.append` will result in the value being stringified](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-urlsearchparams). I assume that's by calling the `Array.prototype.toString()` method on it, which omits the array brackets.

So, you'll either need to concatenate some brackets onto that string, or call a different method (like `JSON.stringify` mentioned in the comments) to keep the brackets.